# Why is slime working in emacs but not in the minimal set-up?

Tags: slime

I am quite new to Emacs. Hence, I have been using the minimal set-up version. However, slime seems to work only on the full version.

If I do on my Ubuntu 20.04 terminal the following:

```
emacs
```

And then, inside emacs:

```
M-x slime
```

I have slime working perfectly. However, if I use the minimal setup version with:

```
emacs -nw -Q
```

After typing M-x slime I get the following error version:

```
M-x slime (no match)
```

Is there something I could to run the Smile REPL inside emacs minimal set-up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slime isn't part of the base Emacs install. You need to add it to your config. Usually this is done via `package-install-packages`, but you may have downloaded the code yourself.

Regardless of how you installed slime, using it requires you load the appropriate configuration code. When you start emacs with `emacs -Q`, you are explicitly telling Emacs to ignore all your configuration, including the code that tells it to use slime.